# Read contract suddenly not working on testnet explorer

Tags: contract-development, tokens, testnets, binance-smart-chain, bscscan

I have a contract I deployed last week. I was able to verify the contract on BSCScan Testnet explorer and successfully use the balanceOf() view function to return an address' balance. However today, I opened up the same contract in the explorer, attempted to view balanceOf() again and got this:

```
[ balanceOf method Response ]
uint256 :  Error: Wrong response id "0" (expected: "1") in {"jsonrpc":"2.0"
"id":1
"method":"eth_call"
"params":[{"from":"0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000"

 "data":"0x70a0823100000000000000000000000041515a61d25f2f2e16084e79bb06824bb6d7d0bf"
"to":"0xc4f2995c6e374781337c14fcd56f7be2a99a3cab"}
 "latest"]}
```

Anyone know wtf this is?